# DotNetNuke - how to change default portal alias in Webinterface

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

In DotNetNuke, I have added multiple URL aliases for a portal. The first one added is the default alias which cannot be removed or changed.

Of course I can do this in the Portal alias table in the database directly (using Management Studio), but people who have no access can't. Is there a way? It seems like such an obvious need - but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the Portal Aliases directly in DotNetNuke.

As Admin select Admin|Site Settings, Advanced, Portal Alises to view/edit the values for that portal.

As Host, select Host|Portals, edit any portal, Advanced, Portal Aliases to view/edit any portal.

Portal aliases do not change very often but you can easily assign a user to the administrators role if they really need access. The reason you can't modify the current portalalias is that you would disable your own access to the portal.

Note that modifying the portalalias through SSMS may break working DNN portals.

Also note the application should be restarted to reflect portal alias changes (via IIS Manager or editing web.config). You must be logged in as a host to use host settings to restart the application via DotNetNuke.